# Why is 'edit' not finding emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, edit

I'm trying to make the 'edit' command use emacs (homebrew-installed)in the OS X terminal.

Whenever I try it, I get:

```
> edit
-bash: edit: command not found
```

I've tried, in my .bashrc file

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/emacs"
```

and just

```
export EDITOR=emacs
```

in my .bashrc.

No luck.

Trying to solve the problem, I've tried:

```
> which emacs
/usr/local/bin/emacs

> type -a emacs
emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs
emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs
emacs is /usr/bin/emacs
emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs
```

Comment: Where should `edit` come from exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question asks why `edit` isn't finding `emacs`, but that's not actually your problem. Your problem is that you don't have an `edit` command to begin with.

You can use the following alias to create `edit`:

```
alias edit="eval \$EDITOR"
```

Comment: jesus h christ, what a fool i've been. i assumed that 'edit' was a command since I'd seen it before and it was mentioned in the 'get started' section here: http://cocoapods.org .. i think 'edit' is the command line version of 'TextWrangler', an aging mac text editor

Answer (score 1):

`edit` is not a bash `builtin`:

```
anew@Wintermute:~$ man builtin | grep edit
anew@Wintermute:~$
```

Certain *nix programs will look for `$EDITOR` and invoke it (cvs, svn, git, etc), but your shell is looking for a command called `edit` in your `$PATH`.